# Installing npm packets

Tags: python, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNp1A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrPRo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quOdW.png)

I install packages for the project, everything is installed, the node_modules folder appears in the project, but at the last moment, everything crashes when the script for Python starts executing, what could be the problem, did someone come across? First I installed the latest version of Python, the errors were the same, I found information that some scripts do not work in version 3, I installed 2.7, but it did not help

Comment: Please *copy* the actual text into the question rather than use images.

Comment: Done, I forgot to add new error text

Answer (score 0):

Based on those symptoms, I'd wager the Python setting in your .npmrc file must be the Python interpreter, not its directory.

I.e. where you now have

```
python = "c:\python27"
```

it should be

```
python = "c:\python27\python.exe"
```

However, since node-gyp can already use the Python launcher to find your Python, you should probably just get rid of that line.

Comment: I use 3.9.5 version of python now
npm config set python c:\python395\python.exe and start npm i
Errors didn't go away:
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "c:\python395\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded c:\python395\python.exe c:\python395\python.exe

Comment: And also:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: c:\python395\python.exe -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
What is it?